# Client is sending empty certificate chain to server despite of it having all the required certificates and keys

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, sslhandshakeexception, jsse

My application is running on jboss 6.4 and trying to communicate to load balancer. When server asks for certificate chain from client (jboss), it sends an empty certificate chain and ssl handshake fails.

I used below command to generate self sign certificate and key in my keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias bliui11345 -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keysize 2048 -keystore bliui.jks
```

CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB

Then I exported certificate

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -file clientcert.pem –keystore bliui.jks -alias bliui11345
```

I installed clientcert.pem in servers truststore. and servers's CA signed cert in my truststore.

I added below connector in my jboss standalone.xml -

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl name="https" password="xyz" certificate-key-file="/opt/eap/standalone/configuration/bliui.jks" verify-client="true" ca-certificate-file="/opt/eap/standalone/configuration/bliui.jks" ca-certificate-password="xyz" ssl-protocol="TLSv1.2"/>
</connector>
```

Despite of adding this connector jboss communicates on 8080.

This is how entry in my keystore looks like

```
Alias name: bliui11345
Creation date: 08-Jul-2019
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Issuer: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Serial number: ******
Valid from: Mon Jul 08 11:34:56 IST 2019 until: Thu Jul 07 11:34:56 IST 2022
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  ***
         SHA1: **
         SHA256: **
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

Keystore also loads properly as I can see loading certificates and keys in jboss logs with debug=ssl

```
Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.42.Final-redhat-2)
Starting Naming Service
Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
trustStore is: /opt/eap/standalone/configuration/bliui.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=Test Global Infrastructure Intermediate CA (7), OU=Test Global Infrastructure Intermediate CA (7), O=Barclays PLC
Issuer:  CN=Test Global Infrastructure Root CA (7), OU=Test Global Infrastructure Root CA (7), O=Barclays PLC
Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4ed6d35d0cf5f88e2162399a05a3c7d1
Valid from Wed May 17 01:00:00 BST 2017 until Fri May 17 00:59:59 BST 2024

Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
***
found key for : bliui11345
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 20684769127101855227492774116772415979402075608086475705872282444802275351603045851226344549731179317732787593894367418004227770753430523757523483229300687424482724535998894744666727437462034313158018417744426363750571388616927327
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Mon Jul 08 07:04:56 BST 2019,
To: Thu Jul 07 07:04:56 BST 2022]
Issuer: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
SerialNumber: [    47fc10c5]
Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-0.0.0.0:8443
Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-0.0.0.0:8080
Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-0.0.0.0:8443
Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-0.0.0.0:8080
Starting deployment of "1.0.012-BLIUI_SuppressedInsights.ear" (runtime-name: "1.0.012-BLIUI_SuppressedInsights.ear")
Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/eap/standalone/deployments
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9999
Listening on 0.0.0.0:4447
```

Client hello -

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  , 58GMT: 1568247549 , bytes = { 41244, , 6763, , 6687, , 161230, , 6550, , 99210, , 213144, , 20220, , 230227, , 210158, , 12095, , 20275, , 95129, , 11094, , 9145, , 14205, , 146226, , 201215, , 161207, , 15196, , 196138, , 112156, , 195217, , 14195 }
Session ID:  , {}
51, 157Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Session ID:   }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
{ Extension extended_master_secret}
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=bliapi-11344.appcloud-np.barcapint.com]
***
```

Server hello -

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
Session ID:  {171, 62, 204, 191, 99, 232, 72, 53, 55, 26, 33, 162, 114, 101, 185, 219, 42, 179, 21, 12, 23, 152, 37, 165, 42, 194, 74, 187, 121, 10, 95, 255}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
update handshake state: server_hello[2]
upcoming handshake states: server certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange[12](optional)
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3682
check handshake state: certificate[11]
update handshake state: certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange[12](optional)
certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
 *** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [ few certificates here]
```

Certificate Request and client certificate chain is empty-

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
check handshake state: server_key_exchange[12]
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB>
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
public x coord: 9119033559767037929973738794301384386482607672191668181147945847562822
public y coord: 2509706886352702164670894720440491148370487015976959327973686224762
 parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

Comment: What is the signature algorithm of the client certificate? Is it in the list sent by the server in the `CertificateRequest`?

Comment: I guess it is  SHA256withRSA . This is how my entry in keystore look like - Alias name: bliui11345
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Issuer: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Serial number: ******
Valid from: Mon Jul 08 11:34:56 IST 2019 until: Thu Jul 07 11:34:56 IST 2022
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  ***
         SHA1: **
         SHA256: **
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Comment: Then I would ask whether the client loaded its keystore correctly. This information is also in the client's JSSE debug log, further up, where it says something like 'added private key'.

Comment: When jboss starts, it says found key for bliui11345, is this what you are talking about?. logs --> found key for : bliui11345
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=BLI, OU=BUK-IIT, O=Bank, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Comment: It would help if you could post both those bits of client JSSE log in your question. They're not legible as comments.

Comment: Did that for you. I can't see anything wrong here. It would now help if you could add all the keymanager output from `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake,keymanager`.

Comment: That's not sufficient. You don't have `keymanager` enabled in this log. It will print some extra stuff before the empty `Certificate` message, ending in the warning.

Comment: @user207421 unfortunately I don't see different logs. Same logs got generated again.

Comment: @user207421 In logs above, it says System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null' , is that a problem?

Comment: Hi I know this is old. But have you solved this issue and how please ?